# Manipulação de arquivos em c++

Tags: c++

Estou tendo problemas ao fazer a manipulação de um arquivo. Sempre da erro nessa parte, especificamente nessa linha "while(getline(alunosE, linha)){", e não sei o porque.

```
ifstream alunosL;
string linha;
alunosE.open("alunos.txt");
if(alunosE.is_open()){
    while(getline(alunosE, linha)){
        cout << linha <<endl;
    }
    alunosE.close();
}
else {
    cout<<"erro!"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize do `eof` para saber o final do arquivo:

```
while ( !alunosE.eof() ) {
```

Dessa forma a leitura de linha vai ficar dentro desse `while`, veja o código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream alunosE;
    string linha;
    alunosE.open("alunos.txt");

    if(alunosE.is_open()){
        while ( !alunosE.eof() ) {
            getline(alunosE, linha);
            cout << linha << endl;
        }

        alunosE.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "erro!" << endl;
    }
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/DefiniteSunnyAnalysts